# Proxy Python HTTPS (with ssl and socket)

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, proxy, https-proxy-agent

I spend a week with my code, I try to make a proxy capable of handling http and https requests but I can't do it with https. Here is my server code :

Server.py

```
import socket
import threading
import time
import ssl

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.blocked_urls = []
        self.cache = {}
        self.cache_expiry = {}  # Store timestamp for cache expiry
        self.cache_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
    
    def handle_client(self, client_socket):
        # Receive data from the client
        request = client_socket.recv(1024)
        start_time = time.time()  # Start timer
        if request.startswith(b'CONNECT'):
            self.handle_https(client_socket, request)
        else:
            self.handle_http(client_socket, request)
        end_time = time.time()  # End timer
        duration = end_time - start_time
        print("[*] Request duration: {:.6f} seconds".format(duration))
    
    def handle_http(self, client_socket, request):
        # Extract domain from the HTTP request
        lines = request.split(b'\r\n')
        host_header = next((line for line in lines if line.startswith(b'Host:')), None)
        if host_header:
            domain = host_header.split(b' ')[1].decode()
        else:
            return

        if domain in self.blocked_urls:
            print("[*] URL Blocked: {}".format(domain))
            client_socket.close()
            return

        # Check if the response is in cache and not expired
        with self.cache_lock:
            if domain in self.cache and time.time() < self.cache_expiry[domain]:
                print("[*] Serving from cache: {}".format(domain))
                response = self.cache[domain]
            else:
                # Connect to the remote server specified in the HTTP request
                remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                remote_socket.connect((domain, 80))

                # Send the HTTP request to the remote server
                remote_socket.send(request)

                # Receive the response from the remote server
                start_time = time.time()  # Start timer for response time
                response = remote_socket.recv(4096)
                end_time = time.time()  # End timer for response time
                duration = end_time - start_time
                print("[*] Response received in {:.6f} seconds".format(duration))

                # Cache the response
                self.cache[domain] = response
                # Set expiry time to 60 seconds
                self.cache_expiry[domain] = time.time() + 60

                # Close the remote socket
                remote_socket.close()

                # Calculate bandwidth used
                bandwidth = len(response) / duration  # Bytes per second
                print("[*] Bandwidth used: {:.2f} bytes/second".format(bandwidth))

        # Send the response back to the client
        client_socket.send(response)

        # Close client socket
        client_socket.close()

    def handle_https(self, client_socket, request):
        # Extract domain from the HTTP request
        lines = request.split(b'\r\n')
        host_header = next((line for line in lines if line.startswith(b'Host:')), None)
        if host_header:
            domain = host_header.split(b' ')[1].decode()
        else:
            return

        if domain in self.blocked_urls:
            print("[*] URL Blocked: {}".format(domain))
            client_socket.close()
            return
        domain_without_port = domain.replace(":443", "")
        # Connect to the remote server specified in the HTTPS request
        remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote_socket.connect((domain_without_port, 443))  # HTTPS typically uses port 443

        # Wrap the socket with SSL context
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
        ssl_context.check_hostname = False
        ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

        remote_ssl_socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(remote_socket, server_hostname=domain)

        # Send the CONNECT request to the remote server
        remote_ssl_socket.send(request)

        # Receive the response from the remote server
        response = remote_ssl_socket.recv(4096)

        # Send the response back to the client
        client_socket.send(response)

        # Relay data between client and server
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                break
            remote_ssl_socket.send(data)

            response = remote_ssl_socket.recv(4096)
            if not response:
                break
            client_socket.send(response)

        # Close the sockets
        remote_ssl_socket.close()
        client_socket.close()


    def proxy_server(self, bind_ip, bind_port):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
        server.listen(5)
        print("[*] Listening on {}:{}".format(bind_ip, bind_port))
        print("[*] List of commands :")
        print("  -b 'URLadresse' => block URL")
        print("  -u 'URLadresse' => unblock URL")

        while True:
            client, addr = server.accept()
            print("[*] Accepted connection from: {}:{}".format(addr[0], addr[1]))

            # Create a thread to handle the client
            client_handler = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client,))
            client_handler.start()

    def user_input_thread(self):
        while True:
            user_input = input()
            user_input_split = user_input.split(" ")
            if user_input_split and '-b' == user_input_split[0]:
                with self.lock:
                    if len(user_input_split) > 1:
                        self.blocked_urls.append(user_input_split[1])
                        print("* Adresse ajoutée à la liste des URL bloquées.")
                    else:
                        print("* Veuillez spécifier une URL à bloquer.")
            elif user_input_split and '-u' == user_input_split[0]:
                with self.lock:
                    if len(user_input_split) > 1:
                        if user_input_split[1] in self.blocked_urls:
                            self.blocked_urls.remove(user_input_split[1])
                            print("* Adresse retirée de la liste des URL bloquées.")
                        else:
                            print("* L'adresse spécifiée n'est pas dans la liste des URL bloquées.")
                    else:
                        print("* Veuillez spécifier une URL à débloquer.")
            else:
                print("* Commande inconnue")

    def run(self):
        bind_ip = '0.0.0.0'  # Listen on all network interfaces
        bind_port = 8081 # Listening port
        self.proxy_server(bind_ip, bind_port)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxy = Proxy()
    threading.Thread(target=proxy.user_input_thread).start()  # Start the user input thread
    proxy.run()
```

I'm testing with this client code:

```
import socket

def test_handle_https(proxy_host, proxy_port):
    # Create a socket connection to the proxy server
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((proxy_host, proxy_port))

    # Send a sample HTTPS request using the CONNECT method
    domain = "www.example.com"
    port = 443
    https_request = f'CONNECT {domain}:{port} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {domain}:{port}\r\n\r\n'
    client_socket.sendall(https_request.encode())

    # Receive and print the response
    response = client_socket.recv(4096)
    print(response.decode())

    # Close the client socket
    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxy_host = '127.0.0.1'  # Proxy server IP address
    proxy_port = 8081  # Proxy server port
    test_handle_https(proxy_host, proxy_port)
```

but I've this answer on my client side :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 349
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 02 Mar 2024 15:17:47 GMT
Server: ECSF (nyd/D119)
```

I don't know what to do, I don't undestand where the error comes from

Comment: *"# Send the CONNECT request to the remote server"* - that's not how CONNECT works. CONNECT is only used to create a tunnel between the client and the proxy. After the connection to the upstream according to the information in the CONNECT request is done  the client gets a successful response from the proxy and from then one all traffic from client to proxy gets passed to the server and all traffic from the server to the client. See [RFC 2817](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2817)